# Getter for boost::variant object

Tags: c++, boost

I have a getter object that returns an object of type Type, defined as follows:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> Empty;
```

It is often the case that I will have neither an int nor a string to return and will have to instead return an empty state. How do you think I return this state?

a) typedef an Empty type and add it to the variant: `boost::variant<int, std::string, Empty>`.

b) return Type()

c) Cast an exception

d) return a boost::shared_ptr, which points to NULL in the case of empty.

Comment: This "empty type" is provided by `boost::empty` and in fact, a `variant`'s `.empty()` function will `return` true if and only if the current value is of the `boost::empty` type. In all other cases, it will return `false`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `boost::blank` for a variant that can have nothing in it. Thus, your variant typedef looks like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<boost::blank, int, std::string> Empty;
```

`blank` is designed specifically for this, and `variant` has special code based on it. By using it, you get a no-memory-allocation guarantee on copying (if the members don't allocate on copy). So that's good.

Since your variant can be "empty", it is important that all of your processing visitors can handle it. It's often more convenient to add an additional visitor pathway than to have a number of conditionals based on an `optional` or something. The different code pathways will be localized to the visitors, which often makes more sense than an `optional<variant>`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a `boost::optional`, this has a simple test (convertible to boolean) to determine if there is a valid value assigned - then you don't need to pollute your variant with an "empty" state. e.g.

```
boost::optional<boost::variant<... > > some_func()
{
:
}
```

Remember to use in place construction in your function when you actually need to return something.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common approach if there is a possibility that the method can't return an object - make the method returning a bool:

```
bool get_value(Type& type) {
  if ( /*check variant emptyness*/) // one can use this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7668530/670719
    return false;
  // else assign type 
}
```

Comments on your solutions:

a) if you will return Empty you will still have to do a check after a method call. So why adding more types if there is a built-in bool already.

b) Type() can have the same value as a legal variable

c) exception is for something exceptional, but from your description "it is often"

d) your problem is that you can't use Type and at the same time can't return boost::variant, so adding one more type with additional ownership issues brings more questions on what is going on without solving initial issue of clean interface.

Comment: It’s a common approach, but not a particularly clean one. Use the *return type* to return data, not output arguments.

Comment: The approach is clean since it uses just built-in bool and user will be aware of the use model since he will not be able to compile `Type type = instance.get_value().` If the requester doesn't want to disclose that he stores a value in `boost::variant` (this is a detail of implementation) I can't get the solution of using `boost::optional` or checking for Empty and so on. These solutions are not flexible and overkill.

Comment: Sorry but your argument just doesn’t follow. The proper way of doing this is to use the return value, end of story. There are several different ways of accomplishing that goal (notably empty variant, using an option type, or, as a pedestrian approach, using a `pair<result_type, bool>`, like e.g. `std::set::insert` does). All of those are cleaner and *don’t* leak implementation details, despite what you’ve claimed. None of these solutions are “not flexible”. None of these solutions are “overkill” (what does that even mean? Syntactically they are certainly *less* burdensome than your code).

Comment: The fact is that `pair<result_type, bool>` requires more code to work with on user side than my approach. And there is no advantage to have this in return value because you still have to check availability of a value before assignment. 
Not flexible means if you usually return not a "boost::variant" but a concrete type

Comment: Wrong. The fundamental difference is that your code requires a variable to be declared and initialised *beforehand*. This places not only a syntactical hurdle, it also changes the semantics in some cases. For instance, it prevents the variable from being `const`. Re “more flexible”, my last comment has given three solutions, two of which work for all types. And with the `variant`, you do **not** have to check for availability of the value before using it, if you are using the variant properly. That is one if its main strengths.

Comment: OK, I can agree that `const` requires some more code with my approach, such as making additional temporary variable.

My point on not using boost::variant as a return type was based on understanding that if there were no empty case the result would be a concrete type.

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for describing the point of `std::pair` of `std::set::insert`

Comment: @KonradRudolph still, you want to use `const` also in cases where you do not want to change the returning object (and do not make an additional copy). And if the returning object can be missing you can't return std::pair<bool, cosnt Type&>. In the case my approach is more handy. So there is no "end of story" solution.